# Page wont submit via post. Using JS to submit via <a href>

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to make my page submit. I dont want to use `<input>` for styling reasons so I am using an `<a href>` tag for my submit button and attempting to use `Javascript` to submit the form.

So I have the form. Note: the form is `echo`ed out via PHP.

```
<form method=\"post\" name=\"roomSubmit\" >
    <textarea cols=\"40\" rows=\"1\" type=\"text\" name=\"roomName\" id=\"regularInput\"></textarea>
    <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"document.forms['roomSubmit'].submit();\" class=\"button button-small\">Create</a>
</form>
```

So as you can see the form name is `roomSubmit`. I need the information in the textarea to be put into a PHP `$_POST` variable.

When i do:
`var_dump $_POST;` after attempting to submit using that button, it doesn't show anything in the POST array.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: when u clikc the <a> does the page refresh, or it goes to the top and add the # at the end of the url ?

Comment: Styling reasons  could you please expand on that a little more? Im sure you can style it the same way

Comment: @AmirBawab the page refreshes and the # appears then disappears rapidly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progressive enhancement favors styling an input, so `@onsy` has the right idea. I would have your HTML like:

```
<input type='submit' class='button button-small' name='sub' id='sub' value='Create' />
```

Now your CSS can look like:

```
.button-small#sub{
  display:inline-block; text-decoration:underline; padding:0; border:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I dont want to use `<input>`. Have a read of the OP, its for styling reasons :) ". I dont want to use <input> for styling reasons so I am using an <a href> tag for my submit button and attempting to use Javascript to submit the form." Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need an action for your form. For example:

`<form action='index.php'...`

or

`<form action='<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>'...`

Comment: Thank you, I was assuming that due to HTML5 an action attribute wasn't required. I was wrong... Thank you for correctly addressing my question as I did say I wanted to use `<a href>` and not `<button>` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of submitting the form through Javascript. Use a

```
<button type="submit">Create</button>
```

element instead. (They are easier to style and can look like `<a>` tags by removing border and background in CSS). 
Your form also needs an `action=` attribute.

Comment: As mentioned the backslashes are because I am `echo`ing out the code via PHP. It is escaping the `"`.

Comment: Ah no problem. Your actual issue is probably because your `action` isn't specified (set it to the current page URL). But using a `button` element in general is still a better approach because then your form can still work without Javascript

Answer (score 0):

First put the action attribute in the form:

```
<form attribute="..." method="post" etc...
```

second change the onclick content to:
try this: `onclick=\"document.roomSubmit.submit(); return false;\"`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. what PHP version are you using? Mine is working:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
echo"<form method=\"post\" name=\"roomSubmit\" >
    <textarea cols=\"40\" rows=\"1\" type=\"text\" name=\"roomName\" id=\"regularInput\"></textarea>
    <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"document.forms['roomSubmit'].submit();\" class=\"button button-small\">Create</a>
</form>";
?>
```